# JS to automatically convert text in parentheses with specific markup including match

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipped

Upon page loading, I want to find all text in the body that is encapsulated in parenthess (here's an example) and replace it with the following:

```
<sup><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip" title="here's an example"></i></sup>
```

I don't have the element's ID. There could be zero or more instances in a page. The text inside the parentheses would then become the title of the .  The text may have quotation marks.

Comment: What html editor do you use within your site?

Comment: ckeditor.  Are you thinking perhaps there's something within that which can do the processing at time of writing?  That might be better than JS at the time of reading (from a performance standpoint).  I hadn't thought of that.  I've tried tweaking ckeditor in the past with no luck.  The documentation never seems to match what I'm looking at.  Possibly the ckeditor I'm using is modded for the ecommerce software I'm using (zencart)

Comment: Seems to me it would be most sensible place to modify your html. Should be able to find a plugin to do this or create a custom style template

Comment: Although... then it would change how it is presented to ME as I go to edit, right?  I mean, if it is actually changing the source then if I go back to edit I would not see ((my thoughts)) but rather the lightbulb icon.  I'd rather the source stay as I write it and it be presented with the swap to the reader.

Comment: Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Upon page loading, I want to find all text in the body that is
>   encapsulated in parentheses.. and replace it...

You could use regex to find text between a pattern and replace it.

*For example:*

```
text.replace(
    /(\{)(.*?)(\})/gi, 
    '<sup><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip" title="$2"></i></sup>'
);
```

Where, the first group matches an opening brace `{`, the last group matches a closing brace `}` and the second group matches zero or more of any character i.e. all text in between. From these matched groups, we then replace the second group by way of the `$2` placeholder in the replacement.

> I don't have the element's ID. There could be zero or more instances
>   in a page.

If you know that all your elements containing such text are same elements, then use a `getElementsByTagName` to get all such elements. If not, then it would be better if you could provide a common class to all such elements which you could then target with `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`.

*For example:*

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
[].forEach.call(p, function(elem) {
    // do the replacement here
});
```

> The text inside the parentheses would then become the title of the .
>   The text may have quotation marks

Just replace the required text within the `title` attribute of your `i` tag in the replacement string. Even better, use a `data-title` attribute so that you could the use CSS or any other Javascript library to show beautiful popup tooltips whenever you want.

For the quotes, use double-quotes for the attribute values and single quotes for your apostrophes inside the text. That would require no extra effort at your end.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LL4seepp/**

**Snippet:**

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'), 
    text, converted;

[].forEach.call(p, function(elem) {
    var original = elem.innerHTML, replaced;
    replaced = original.replace(/(\{)(.*?)(\})/gi, 
  '<sup><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip" data-title="$2"></i></sup>'
 );
 elem.innerHTML = replaced;
});
```

```css
i.tooltip {
    display: inline-block; position: relative;
    width: 0.75em; height: 0.75em; border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #c33; cursor: help;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
i.tooltip::after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    position: absolute; z-index: 100;
    top: -200%; left: 120%; opacity: 0;
    padding: 0px; text-align: center;
    width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #edb; border: 0px solid #666;
    transition: all 250ms 250ms ease; 
}
i.tooltip:hover::after {
    display: block; padding: 4px; 
    width: 128px; height: 1em; opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid #333; 
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<p>
    I want to write the way I write, but not force it down my readers throats. I often have side thoughts {like this} which I always put inside parenthesis {like so}.
    But I don't want to change the way I write. So I wondered... is it possible to take anything I write in parenthesis {here's an example} and re-write it.
</p>
<p>
    I want to write the way I write, but not force it down my readers throats. I often have side thoughts {like this with 'quotes'} which I always put inside parenthesis {like so}.
    But I don't want to change the way I write. So I wondered... is it possible to take anything I write in parenthesis {here's an example} and re-write it.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this problem!

My approach would be to loop through the document's paragraphs, collecting all the double-bracketed side-comments into an array, first.

That way, you can subsequently display (or re-display) the side-comments as superscripts, *or* as footnotes *or* as end-notes (etc.)

```js
// Initialise variables
var paragraphsNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var paragraphText = [];
var text = '';

// Collect all paragraphs in the document into one long text string
for (var p = 0; p < paragraphsNodeList.length; p++) {
text += paragraphsNodeList[p].innerHTML;
text += ' ';
}

// Harvest the tooltips from the long text string, collect them into an array, tidy them up
var tooltips = text.match(/\(\([^\)]+\)\)/g);

for (var t = 0; t < tooltips.length; t++) {
tooltips[t] = tooltips[t].replace("((", "");
tooltips[t] = tooltips[t].replace("))", "");
}

// Loop through each paragraph, replacing each side-comment with a superscript element
for (var p = 0; p < paragraphsNodeList.length; p++) {
paragraphText[p] = paragraphsNodeList[p].innerHTML;
paragraphText[p] = paragraphText[p].replace(/\(\([^\)]+\)\)/g, ('<sup></sup>'));
paragraphsNodeList[p].innerHTML = paragraphText[p];
}

// Loop through all the superscript elements, adding the relevant markup and tooltip
var supNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('sup');

for (var s = 0; s < supNodeList.length; s++) {
supNodeList[s].innerHTML = ('<i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip" title="' + tooltips[s] + '">' + (s + 1) + '</i>');
}
```

```css
h2 {
margin: 24px 0 4px;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2:nth-of-type(1) {
margin-top: 12px;
}

div, p {margin-bottom: 12px;}

h2 + div, h2 + p {
margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Before</h2>
<div>I was idly wondering the other day ((I tend to do this a lot)) about whether it might be possible ((practically, rather than theoretically)) to convert all my own interjections and clarifications into super-scripted tool-tips for the purposes of abbreviating any hypertext that I write ((since we all know that people approach reading on-screen hypertext in a different manner from long-form print articles and in the former case, a tendency towards brevity and / or conciseness tends, generally, to be the preferable option)).</div>

<div>It is my intention ((as stated above)) to convert all my musings into ((initially invisible)) tooltips via javascript ((assuming that this is actually possible)).</div>

<h2>After</h2>
<p>I was idly wondering the other day ((I tend to do this a lot)) about whether it might be possible ((practically, rather than theoretically)) to convert all my own interjections and clarifications into super-scripted tool-tips for the purposes of abbreviating any hypertext that I write ((since we all know that people approach reading on-screen hypertext in a different manner from long-form print articles and in the former case, a tendency towards brevity and / or conciseness tends, generally, to be the preferable option)).</p>

<p>It is my intention ((as stated above)) to convert all my musings into ((initially invisible)) tooltips via javascript ((assuming that this is actually possible)).</p>
```

## =====

**Improved Version with Better Looking Tooltips**

```js
// Initialise variables
var paragraphsNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var paragraphText = [];
var text = '';

// Collect all paragraphs in the document into one long text string
for (var p = 0; p < paragraphsNodeList.length; p++) {
text += paragraphsNodeList[p].innerHTML;
text += ' ';
}

// Harvest the tooltips from the long text string, collect them into an array, tidy them up
var tooltips = text.match(/\(\([^\)]+\)\)/g);

for (var t = 0; t < tooltips.length; t++) {
tooltips[t] = tooltips[t].replace("((", "[...] ");
tooltips[t] = tooltips[t].replace("))", " [...]");
}

// Loop through each paragraph, replacing each side-comment with a superscript element
for (var p = 0; p < paragraphsNodeList.length; p++) {
paragraphText[p] = paragraphsNodeList[p].innerHTML;
paragraphText[p] = paragraphText[p].replace(/\(\([^\)]+\)\)/g, ('<sup></sup>'));
paragraphsNodeList[p].innerHTML = paragraphText[p];
}

// Loop through all the superscript elements, adding the relevant markup and tooltip
var supNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName('sup');

for (var s = 0; s < supNodeList.length; s++) {
supNodeList[s].innerHTML = ('<i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip">' + (s + 1) + '</i><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip">' + (s + 1) + '. ' + tooltips[s] + '</i>');
}
```

```css
body {
max-width: 720px;
}

h2 {
margin: 24px 0 4px;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2:nth-of-type(1) {
margin-top: 12px;
}

div, p {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

h2 + div, h2 + p {
margin-top:0;
}

sup i {
position: relative;
top: -4px;
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
padding: 1px;
border: 1px solid rgba(127,0,0,1);
background: rgba(255,255,127,1);
width: auto;
height: auto;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 8px;
}

sup i:nth-of-type(even) {
display: none;
opacity: 0;
}

sup:hover i:nth-of-type(odd) {
display: none;
}

sup:hover i:nth-of-type(even) {
z-index: 12;
display: inline-block;
opacity: 0;
width: 180px;
padding: 4px;
margin-right: -182px;
margin-bottom: -100%;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 13px;
transition: all 0.75s ease-in;
}

sup:hover i:nth-of-type(even):hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Before</h2>
<div>I was idly wondering the other day ((I tend to do this a lot)) about whether it might be possible ((practically, rather than theoretically)) to convert all my own interjections and clarifications into super-scripted tool-tips for the purposes of abbreviating any hypertext that I write ((since we all know that people approach reading on-screen hypertext in a different manner from long-form print articles and in the former case, a tendency towards brevity and / or conciseness tends, generally, to be the preferable option)).</div>

<div>It is my intention ((as stated above)) to convert all my musings into ((initially invisible)) tooltips via javascript ((assuming that this is actually possible)).</div>

<h2>After</h2>
<p>I was idly wondering the other day ((I tend to do this a lot)) about whether it might be possible ((practically, rather than theoretically)) to convert all my own interjections and clarifications into super-scripted tool-tips for the purposes of abbreviating any hypertext that I write ((since we all know that people approach reading on-screen hypertext in a different manner from long-form print articles and in the former case, a tendency towards brevity and / or conciseness tends, generally, to be the preferable option)).</p>

<p>It is my intention ((as stated above)) to convert all my musings into ((initially invisible)) tooltips via javascript ((assuming that this is actually possible)).</p>
```

Comment: It is dead obvious that you, my friend, understand my problem :)  I believe we probably write in similar style.

Comment: Heh, thanks. I have to admit, although my original solution simply used the `title` attribute as a tooltip (following the example in your question), I was subsequently quite envious of @Abhitalks' better-looking, animated tooltips. So I have improved my CSS, marginally tweaked my script and added a second version of my solution (enhanced from the original) to my post above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.  Use regex to find and replace "((" and "))".  Given this content:

```
<div id="content">without my having to actually DO anything special with the content? I could get in the habit of doubling up on the parenthesis if that helps ((like this would be a tooltip)) but (this would not).</div>
```

This code will search it and replace with your icon.

```
var target = document.getElementById('content'),
    str = target.innerHTML,
    pre = '<sup><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip" title="',
    post = '"></i></sup>';
str = str.replace(/\(\(/g, pre).replace(/\)\)/g, post);
target.innerHTML = str;
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/fzn4trmL/

The title attribute doesn't have a lot of flexibility and this will have problems.  You'd be much better off just surrounding the text by the icon, like so:

```
<i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o tooltip">like this would be a tooltip</i>
```

But then you need to have the tooltip show the html in the icon instead of the title.